# How to find a set(s) contain most parts of my wanted parts list

Tags: piece-information, sets

I have a parts wanted list (in BrickLlink) and I want to buy a set contain most of my parts wanted list.

Does there is a way to import a part list and find which set(s) contain most of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never tried it, but I suspect you can do this with Rebrickable.com. It lets you upload MOCs, which must have an inventory. It then lets you see how close your collection comes to building that set, including some possible piece substitution (i.e. similar parts, related molds, ignore colour, etc). Finally, it recommends sets to buy to increase your total. To my knowledge it doesn't try to optimize the "purchase" list to maximize coverage or keep costs down, but it should at least give you some candidates.

For example, when I try to build [this MOC](http://rebrickable.com/mocs/lucrichters/2-6-6-6-allegheny), it tells me I'm missing a bunch of black pieces:

[image]

Then it suggests some sets I might buy:

[image]

Note that the suggested sets are not always practical.

Comment: It's really a very nice workaround !! Thank you !